# Comparing Stash variable to segment fails

Tags: stash, conditionals

I asked this also on Devotee - apologies for posting in both places but I guess here is better.

I’m setting several variables in the Channel Entries loop like so:

> {exp:stash:set name="var1" parse_tags="yes"}{custom_field}{/exp:stash:set}

Then outputting them later outside the channel like this:

> {exp:stash:get name="var1" default="uff" process="end"}

Which works fine. But then I want to compare “var1” to Segment_3 but can’t find any syntax/conditional which will work…either it outputs nothing or both conditions are true - have tried with If/else plugin too.

I’m guessing it’s parse order? What’s the way to compare these values? I tried with this conditional:

> {if segment_3 == "{exp:stash:get name='var1'}"}Success!{/if}

And it returns nothing when the condition is actually true and the ‘success’ when it’s false. Which is odd. Anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a parse order issue: the conditional is being run before the stash variable is set. There may be a more efficient approach, but you can use [stash parse](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3astash%3aparse%7D) to make it parse later:

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    {if "{segment_3}" == "{exp:stash:get name='var1'}"}Success!{/if}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

(note the change to segment variable)

Or if you can use a [snippet](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Variables#wiki-ifelse-advanced-conditionals), try:

```
{exp:stash:set name="sn_var1" type="snippet"}{custom_field}{/exp:stash:set}
```

and retrieving:

```
{if sn_var1 == segment_3}success{/if}
```

Comment: This first one worked for me Romans...thanks!